# Writing a list to a file and reading the contents back into a list using simplejson

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I would like to write a list to a file and read back the contents of the file into a list.
I am able to write the list to the file using simplejson as follows:

```
f = open("data.txt","w")
l = ["a","b","c"]
simplejson.dump(l,f)
f.close()
```

Now to read the file back i do

```
file_contents = simplejson.load(f)
```

But, i guess file_contents is in json format. Is there any way to convert it to a list ?

Thank You.

Comment: When you print `file_contents` what do you see?  Don't guess, actually show the actual value, please.

Comment: That means it's a list already... The prefix `u` is saying that the strings are unicode, but it's doing exactly what you wanted...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
  filecontents = simplejson.load(f)
```

is indeed reloading the data exactly as you specify.  What may be confusing you is that all strings in JSON are *always* Unicode -- JSON (like Javascript) doesn't have a "byte string" data type distinct from "unicode".

**Edit** I don't have the old `simplejson` around any more (since its current version has become part of the standard Python library as `json`), but here's how it works (making `json` masquerade as `simplejson` in the hope of avoiding confusing you!-)...:

```
>>> import json
>>> simplejson = json
>>> f = open("data.txt","w")
>>> l = ["a","b","c"]
>>> simplejson.dump(l,f)
>>> f.close()
>>> with open("data.txt") as f: fc = simplejson.load(f)
... 
>>> fc
[u'a', u'b', u'c']
>>> fc.append("d")
>>> fc
[u'a', u'b', u'c', 'd']
>>>
```

If this exact code (net of the first two lines if what you do instead is `import simplejson` of course;-) doesn't match what you observe, you've found a bug, so it's crucial to report what versions of Python and `simplejson` you're using and exactly what error you get, complete with traceback (edit your Q to add this -- obviously crucial -- info!).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But,im unable to append new items to filecontents. For example after filecontents = simplejson.load(f), if i do filecontents.append("d"), the program gives errors. Any way to fix this ? Thank You.

Comment: @Tom, I just ran through the exact code from your question on 2.6 an I can append to the resulting list. Also, no unicode strings.

Comment: @Tom, "gives errors" without any clarity about which ones (edit your Q to add the traceback!) looks like an attempt to stop anybody from being able to help you -- just like the total lack of info about what Python version and simplejson version and simplejson version you use, of course;-).  Still, I've edited my A to show how the code gives absolutely no errors to me on Python 2.6 (though of course it *does* give unicode strings, contrary to @aaron's astonishing comment in the matter).

Comment: is there any difference between `import json as simplejson` vs what you did? Just curious to know why you did it that way.

Comment: @Chinmay, no difference -- I had just done `import json` in that interactive session before I thought of the name issue, so I fixed it with the minimum number of character;-).

Answer (score -1):

The `.read_file` and `.write_file` options for [Unipath](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath) really make this simple.